# when <input> html is empty then hide <div> logic

Tags: jquery

I have 3 markup fields, i just want a basic logic that if these fields are left blank, then this `<div id="category">` will not display.

[EDIT] Updated

```
<div id="panel"> 
<div id="form">

    <div class="input-prepend">
               <span class="add-on">name</span>
       <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">last name</span>
      <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Your Lastname">
    </div>

    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">email</span>
      <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>

 </div> <!--/form-->
</div>  <!--/panel-->     

<!--DROPDOWN-->
<select id="category">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a category</option>
        <option name="choice1" value="blue"> blue  </option>
        <option name="choice2" value="red"> red    </option>
        <option name="choice3" value="pink"> pink  </option>
        <option name="choice4" value="yellow"> yellow </option>
        <option name="choice5" value="violet"> violet </option>
</select>
```

this is my jquery, and it doenst seem to work to me.

```
if ($j(".required").is(':empty')) {
    $j("#category").hide();
} else {
    $j('#category').show();
}
```

Comment: typo here `sj('#category').show();`

Comment: put more of your html, and tell us what you want the behavior if some inputs are empty and some are not ?

Comment: Aside from the typo, you can write this shorter as `$j('#category').toggle($j('.required').val() === '')` - 
Passing a boolean to `.toggle()` will show it for `true`, hide it for `false`.

Comment: $j is used in Wordpress to avoid conflicts in their JQUERY and JS.

Comment: @Anton its just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**

HTML :

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="form">
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">name</span>

            <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">last name</span>

            <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Your Lastname">
        </div>
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">email</span>

            <input class="span3 required" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/form-->
</div>
<!--/panel-->
<!--DROPDOWN-->
<select id="category" style="display:none;">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a category</option>
    <option name="choice1" value="blue">blue</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="red">red</option>
    <option name="choice3" value="pink">pink</option>
    <option name="choice4" value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option name="choice5" value="violet">violet</option>
</select>
```

JS :

```
$j(function () {
    $j(".required").on("keypress keyup change", function () {
        var show_flag = true;
        $('.required').each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                show_flag = false;
            }
        });
        if (show_flag) {
            $("#category").show();
        } else {
            $("#category").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nyzm/E8X5S/3/

Comment: wow! thanks! this worked. previous answers werent working to me. but your answer did. can you kindly explain to me your `line2` & `line3` logic?

Comment: i have 3 <input> as shown above updated code. when i type on the 3rd input, <div id="category"> shows, even if the 2 inputs are empty. what i want is, all 3 `<input>` have values before the `<div>` appears

Comment: what line 2 does, binds `keypress`, `keyup` and `change` events to all elements with `required` class. what line 4 (was line 3) does, loops into all the elements with `required` class.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for this. also, id like to ask if you dont mind. can you please explain this line `$('.required').each(function (i) {` does this mean, for each class with class required, do this function (i). what does the `i` do? i apologize if this is a simple question. just started learning javascript :)

Comment: `$('.required').each(function (i) {` means, for each element with class `required` do the defined function. `i` is the index number of the element. which we dont use here. but might be useful somewhere else. if you `alert(i);` in the function you will see 0, 1, 2 will return.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ($(".required").html().length > 0) {
    $('#category').show();
}
else {
    $("#category").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($j(".required").val('')){
   $('#category').show();
} else {
    $('#category').hide();
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `if($j(".required").val() == '')`. What you have now will set the value to blank.

Comment: checking the value avlue of .required is empty or not

Comment: Yes, that's what you should be doing. The code is not doing that however,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `:empty`, try;

```
if ( !$(".required").val() ) {
    $('#category').hide();
}
else {
    $("#category").show();
}
```

The length check isn't required since an empty string returns false anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("prependedInput").value.toString().Length() > 0) {
    document.getElementById("category").style.display = "block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("category").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$j(".required").keyup(function () {
    if ( $j.trim($j("this").val()) != "" ) {
        $j('#category').show();
    } else {
        $j("#category").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, i like this code, but. it doesnt work to me. i have included the whole `<div>` of my html above.

Answer (score 0):

I've a quick fiddle, you may be interested in.

http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/Jhvt3/

```
$('.required').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).val()=="" ? $('#category').hide() : $('#category').show();
});
```